# How to use/access docker environment variables in Shibboleth xml files?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

I am trying to inject my docker environment variables into my shibboleth2.xml file. Shibboleth does not recognize my environment variables at all.

For example

```
 <ApplicationDefaults entityID="${MY_ENV_VARIABLE}">
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make Shibboleth access these values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envsubst can be used for replacing environment variables in a file.

```
envsubst < input.file > output.file
```